# Optional parameter $path declared before required parameter $langcode is implicitly treated as a required parameter in include_once()

Tags: 7

I've just updated from PHP 7.4 to 8.1 and on the whole everything appears to be working. However I'm seeing the following over and over in our logs, to the point that it's drowning out everything else. Bootstrap.inc looks to be a part of Core? is there a fix for those of us still stuck on Drupal 7?

```
Deprecated function: Optional parameter $path declared before required parameter $langcode is implicitly treated as a required parameter in include_once() (line 1439 of [server_path]/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Comment: Which version of Drupal 7 are you using?

Comment: @misterdidi 7.98